# how to set an OnTouchListener for a PopupWindow?

Tags: android

Here's my code that shows a PopUp when the button is touched and dismisses it, when the user releases his finger.

But I need to know weather the user had just released his finger or did he slide into the popup and release his finger from there.

In my code this doesn't really work, since I guess the popup doesn't get focus without the user releasing his finger. Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks!

```
    LinearLayout LinLay = new LinearLayout(this);
    ImageView ivg = new ImageView(this);
    ivg.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    LinLay.addView(ivg);
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(LinLay, 100, 100, true);

    final Button bt2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bt2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
                {
                pw.showAtLocation(bt2, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
                }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )
                {
                pw.dismiss();
                }
            return true;
        }
        });


    ivg.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )
                {
                showToast(); /// doesn't work! :)
                }
            return true;
        }
        });
    }


public void showToast()
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "AAA!", 500).show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use imageview and imageview onclick()  to display showpopoup() window

```
im = new ImageView(this);
        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn);

        im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopup(R.layout.popup_example);
            }
        });
```

and

```
private void showPopup(int resourses) {

        final LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflate.inflate(resourses, null, false);
        ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view
                .findViewById(R.id.buttonContainer);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                mPopup.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        });

        mPopup = new PopupWindow(view, 160, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, true);
        mPopup.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_InputMethod);
        mPopup.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.LEFT, 0, 10);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! :) But the question was a bit different, I need to find out weather the user had released his finger within the popup or outside of it. Of course, i can use event coordinates, but just thought there might a better way.

Answer (score 1):

obviously ,it does not work. message send as follow:

`ACTION_DOWN`

1. activity :dispatch touch event
2. activity :onUserInteraction
3. layout :dispatch touch event
4. layout :onInterceptTouchEvent
5. button :onTouch(action_down)

`ACTION_UP`

1. activity :dispatch touch event
2. layout :dispatch touch event
3. layout :onInterceptTouchEvent
4. button: ontouch..

so you can see the method can only be transfer to up view.
imageview is the same level to the button..

Comment: If you think about the situation, it's not obvious that it doesn't work. Otherwise the question wouldn't have been asked. What's obvious to you is not always obvious to others.